# MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL servers, Master & Slave , running on Ubuntu 12.04.  I have replication working from the Master to the Slave. If the Master goes down and the Slave is used, how do I get data to replicate back to the Master once it's up ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read:

- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) for MySQL 5.7
- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) for MySQL 5.6
- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) for MySQL 5.5

Once you have switched to the slave (i.e., the slave is the new master), you will have to load a backup onto the old master and start replication towards it exactly as you had previously done with the old slave. In other words, you cannot reuse what you already had on the old master before switching.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need master-master replication approach.

Configure each server as a slave to each other. This way, everything you insert on first server, replicates on second one, and vice versa.

If one got out of production you will use another one. Once it get's back, it will continue parsing relay log files from the last known position and get into sync again.

Hope it helps!